# Multiple DatePicker in JS

Tags: javascript, datepicker

We have created a form, please check below image for reference..

[image]

Firstly, here we have Datepicker with DOR heading, when we click on Add Button which is placed on the bottom... the whole row is duplicated..

Below is the coding in JS

```
$('#inward').on('click', 'button[type="button"]', function () {
$(this).closest('tr').remove();
  })
        $('p button[type="button"]').click(function () {
        $('#inward').append('<tr><td><input type="date[]"  
        name="datePicker[]" id="datePicker[]"  class="form-control 
        input-sm mb10 datePickerBlack" required ></td><td><select 
        name="oretailers[]" id="oretailers[]" class="form-control 
        input-sm mb15 cretailers"><option>- Select Retailers- 
        -</option><?php echo $options; ?></select></td><td><input 
        type="text" name="oitem[]" id="oitem[]" class="form-control 
        input-sm mb15" required></td><td><input type="text" 
        name="oquantity[]" id="oquantity[]" class="form-control input-sm 
        mb15" maxlength="3" onkeypress="javascript:return isNumber 
        (event)" required></td><td><input type="text" name="opackage[]" 
        id="opackage[]" placeholder="W x H x L" class="form-control 
        input-sm mb15" required></td><td><input type="text" 
        name="oweight[]" id="oweight[]" class="form-control input-sm 
        mb15 tweight" onblur="wtotal()" maxlength="5" 
        onkeypress="javascript:return isNumber (event)" required>
        </td><td><input type="text" name="orweight[]" id="orweight[]" 
        class="form-control input-sm mb15" maxlength="5"  
        onkeypress="javascript:return isNumber (event) required">
        </td><td><input type="text" name="ovalue[]" id="ovalue[]" 
        class="form-control input-sm mb15" onkeypress="javascript:return 
        isNumber (event)" required></td><td><button type="button" 
        class="btn btn-inverse"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
        </td></tr>');
});
```

The DatePicker Code :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

   jQuery('.datePickerBlack').datepicker({changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, maxDate : 0});

});
```

My Issue is that on second row when i click the date changes on first row...
all this row will be saved in DB one form is submitted..

Comment: You should initialize the datepickers separately

Comment: separately means..??

Comment: For example, add an id to the datepicker to be div that was last added and then initialiaze it using this id: jQuery('#newId').datepicker()

Comment: You mean i have to create datepicker ID dynamically and add that very same id to datepicker script

Comment: Yes, if user can add n number of new rows, you should generate a random id, to use for datepicker init, otherwise you can hard code it. You can add your id where you append the new row to html, right after the append() call the datepicker init with the id you just appended

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(document).on('focus',".datePickerBlack",function(){
       jQuery('.datePickerBlack').datepicker({changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, maxDate : 0});
    });
});
```

Comment: maintain count in order to keep track of row id and distinguish the element id. For example use id="datePicker[1]" instead of id="datePicker[]" while appending rows.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your quick replies.. i found answer..

Check below code

```
var count = $(".calrow").length
        $('#inward').append('<tr class="calrow"><td><input type="date[]"  name="datePicker[]" id="datePicker'+count+'"  class="form-control input-sm mb10 datePickerBlack" required ></td><td><select name="oretailers[]" id="oretailers" class="form-control input-sm mb15 cretailers"><option>- Select Retailers- -</option><?php echo $options; ?></select></td><td><input type="text" name="oitem[]" id="oitem[]" class="form-control input-sm mb15" required></td><td><input type="text" name="oquantity[]" id="oquantity[]" class="form-control input-sm mb15" maxlength="3" onkeypress="javascript:return isNumber (event)" required></td><td><input type="text" name="opackage[]" id="opackage[]" placeholder="W x H x L" class="form-control input-sm mb15" required></td><td><input type="text" name="oweight[]" id="oweight[]" class="form-control input-sm mb15 tweight" onblur="wtotal()" maxlength="5" onkeypress="javascript:return isNumber (event)" required></td><td><input type="text" name="orweight[]" id="orweight[]" class="form-control input-sm mb15" maxlength="5"  onkeypress="javascript:return isNumber (event) required"></td><td><input type="text" name="ovalue[]" id="ovalue[]" class="form-control input-sm mb15" onkeypress="javascript:return isNumber (event)" required></td><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-inverse"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button></td></tr>');
```

Here i have added a class to tr and got the length and passing that length to datepicker ID

Answer (score -1):

This is what I have created..

```
<input type="button" />
        <div id="inward"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var count = 1;
            $(document).on('focus',".datePickerBlack",function(){
                $('.datePickerBlack').datepicker({minDate:0, dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'});
            });
            $('#inward').on('click', 'button[type="button"]', function () {
                $(this).closest('tr').remove();
            });
            $('[type="button"]').click(function () {
            $('#inward').append('<tr><td><input type="date['+count+']"  '+
                'name="datePicker['+count+']" id="datePicker['+count+']"  class="form-control'+
                'input-sm mb10 datePickerBlack" required ></td><td><button type="button" '+
                'class="btn btn-inverse"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>'+
                '</td></tr>');
           count = count +1;
            }); 
        </script>
```